# Sending an array to device via libssh2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ssh, libssh2

I'm playing around with libssh2 and have managed to get this test application to work on my iPhone (running 5.1.1)

http://www.x2on.de/2011/02/02/libssh2-for-ios-iphone-and-ipad-example-app-with-ssh-connection/#comment-1281

The application connects just fine, but the problem is that the device I'm connecting to is going to receive an array of hex values. My problem is then that I havn't been able to figure out how to do this since to two availble functions to send data over SSH is

**int libssh2_channel_exec(LIBSSH2_CHANNEL *channel, const char *command);**

or

**ssize_t libssh2_channel_write(LIBSSH2_CHANNEL *channel, const char *buf, size_t buflen);**

the data I would like to send is for example

**char buf[6] = {0x00, 0x03, 0x14, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00};**

Anybody who can give me a hand? I'm rather new to the iOS platform, so sorry if it is a very simple question :)

Answer (score 0):

libssh2_channel_write() will send exactly the bytes you ask it to, which very well could be those 6 bytes you showed here.